# Python 3.7 Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having trouble with my first python pong game using tkinter if someone could take a look:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 class Game(tk.Frame):
  game = Game(root)
NameError: name 'Game' is not defined
```

Comment: Indentation matters. `Game(root)` shouldnt be witihin `class Game`. But you also cannot have an empty class body.

Comment: It's unclear this is simply an indentation error. Is there more to the `Game` class or are you trying to create an instance of one inside the class definition. Please [edit] your question and clarify.